# Mongose array inside of array

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, postman, schema

I want to achieve like this:
On every user there's subject, and on every subject there's students.

```
user: [{ subjects: {subjectCode, description},[{students: {name, year, phone}}]}]
```

I already got the users -> subject side.
[image]

my problem now is how can i achieve to create students inside of subjects?

This is for my authentication.
User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Every user can create subjects.
Subject.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SubjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  student: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'student',
    },
  ],
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('subject', SubjectSchema);
```

In every subjects, there's should array of students.
Student.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  year: {
    type: String,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('student', StudentSchema);
```

Comment: it will helpful if you add more details like your tried query, code and example datas not only images.

Comment: hello @turivishal. i updated my question. hope it helps. Btw the users -> create subject part is totally working. my problem now is in every "array of subject" the user can insert student inside of it.

Comment: Also add what have you tried, working part and not working part both.